# Insert data into the temp table with query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to inset data into the temp table with query.

But I got an error saying

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Below the code that I used

```
select * into #Temp1
from
(
    select c.name, t.name, 0 as isSelected
    from sys.columns c
    inner join sys.types t on c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    where object_name(object_id) = 'tblActor'
)
```

Comment: You need a table alias after a subquery in the `from` clause.

Comment: I used x as alias. But i got an error saying. 
The column 'name' was specified multiple times for 'x'.

Comment: Can you please post your code as text, not image?

Comment: Because `name` was specified multiple times, the error is quite helpful here. Your first 2 columns are both called `name`. Alias them as something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please use one of these -**

Please note you need to provide unique names of the columns you are 
inserting. You need to provide an alias to the linked query like i did in second query.

```
SELECT c.name CName, t.name tName, 0 AS isSELECTED
INTO #Temp1
FROM Sys.Columns c
INNER JOIN Sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'tblActor'
```

OR

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp2
FROM 
(
    SELECT c.name CName ,t.name tName,0 AS isSELECTED
    FROM Sys.Columns c
    INNER JOIN Sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'tblActor'
)k
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems in the query.  Just do:

```
select c.name as c_name, t.name as t_name, 0 as isselected
into #temp1
from sys.columns c join
     sys.tables t
     on c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
where object_name(object_id) = 'tblActdor';
```

I'm not sure what the query is supposed to do.  It doesn't really make sense to me.  And, `information_schema.columns` would be a better source of reasonable information.  But this will fix the errors you are getting.

Comment: Thanks got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please use table alias after the `)` in the last line

OR :

```
SELECT 
         col.[name] AS [ColumnName], 
         typ.[name] AS [TypeName], 
         CONVERT(BIT, 0) AS [isSelected] 
INTO #Temp1 
FROM Sys.Columns col 
JOIN Sys.types typ 
ON col.[user_type_id] = typ.[user_type_id] 
WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'tblActor'
```